# Resource Monitor Showing Incorrect (?) CPU Usage for Services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, cpu-usage, resource-management

Resource Monitor on my Windows Server 2012 R2 is showing high CPU usage for process `oracle.exe` (~75%). However, it also shows that CPU usage is divided among totally unrelated services.

[image]

Namely the services Windows Firewall, Shell Hardware Detection, and DHCP Client is sharing ~25% of CPU time each.

How does this make any sense? Is this a bug in Resource Monitor, or am I missing something here?